# Django how to pass value from template to view

Tags: python, django, templates, view

i want this functionality. User enters email address, and somehow it has to be passed to my views.py file, so i could then email the user that he has succesfully registered.

This is my template file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<section>
<h2 style="text-align: center">Register</h2>
<form action="/accounts/register/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

<ul>
{{form.as_ul}}
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="validateForm()"/>

</form>

</section>
{% endblock %}
```

this is my forms.py file:

```
class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    #kokie fields bus displayed html form
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    firstname = forms.CharField(required=True)
    lastname = forms.CharField(required=True)
    whoinvitedyou = forms.CharField(required=True)
    phone = forms.CharField(required=True)
    workplace = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'whoinvitedyou', 'phone', 'workplace')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
#more fields for name last name
        user.firstname = self.cleaned_data['firstname']
        user.lastname = self.cleaned_data['lastname']
        user.whoinvitedyou = self.cleaned_data['whoinvitedyou']
        user.phone = self.cleaned_data['phone']
        user.workplace = self.cleaned_data['workplace']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

this is my views.py:

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')
        else:
            return render_to_response('invalid_reg.html')

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()
    print args
    return render_to_response('register.html', args)
```

how do i pass the value so later i can use it? maybe somebody can help me with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, after the `form.is_valid()` call, the email address will be available in `form.cleaned_data['email']`.  You can use that to send the email after `form.save()`.

Additionally, you might want to look into existing 3rd party libraries like [django-registration](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) as it already does the functionality (emailing the just registered user) that you want.

Answer (score 0):

In order to send an e-mail you don't necessarily need to send the value to a view in `views.py`. 
You can use a `post_save` signal to send an email. You can put the code anywhere, although I usually put it in `models.py`.

Info on signals: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/signals/

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.core.mail import send_mail

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def my_handler(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    send_mail('Subject of email', 'Message body.', 'from@example.com', [instance.email], fail_silently=False)
```

note that `instance.email` is the email address of the user which you just saved, you can access `instance` to retreive more information e.g. the name, so that you can put `"dear "+instance.name` at the beginning of the body for example

Comment: NB the annotation `@receiver(post_save, sender=User)` means that the annotated function (`my_handler`) needs to be executed every time you save a new `User`, after the user is saved.

Comment: thanks! those signals looks hard  to understand :D . but i will definitely look at this topic in the future